# Не входит в метод, потому что там находится класс

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте. *Код ниже работает, если закомментировать весь код, связанный с классом VK, в методе SocialSuicide*

Вопрос 1 (основной): Почему программа не входит в *app.Run()* метода SocialSuicide, когда в методе есть класс?
Вопрос 2 (связанный): Правильно ли использовать класс VK таким образом? Может, его стоит переписать и подключать *как сервис* в методе ConfigureServices?

Видео, в котором показано, что не работает: [тут (4.9 МБ)](http://rgho.st/private/7YclF9cy6/d0e3eb88dc74ccf414f2c9a388c30f1a)

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/social_suicide", SocialSuicide);
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Error 404 - Not Found");
        });
    }

    private static void SocialSuicide(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            var portal = context.Request.Query["portal"];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(portal))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            }
            else
            {
                bool ok = false;
                foreach (string pttrn in _patterns)
                    if (portal == pttrn.ToLower())
                        ok = true;
                if (!ok)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (portal)
                    {
                        case "vk":
                            {
                                if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("l") & context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("p"))
                                {
                                    string login = context.Request.Query["l"];
                                    string password = context.Request.Query["p"];
                                    VK vk = new VK();
                                    try
                                    {
                                        vk.Auth(login, password);
                                        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                                    }
                                    catch (VkNet.Exception.VkApiAuthorizationException)
                                    {
                                        string code = context.Request.Query["c"];
                                        vk.ApplyTwoFactor(code);
                                        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                    context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            string message = context.Response.StatusCode == 400 ? "Error 400 - Bad Request" : (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 ? "Error 404 - Not Found" : (context.Response.StatusCode == 401 ? "Error 401 - Unauthorized" : "Deleted successfully."));
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(message);
        });
    }
```

**VK.cs** (*Подключил VkNet.UWP.dll для работы с API ВКонтакте*)

```
using VkNet;
using VkNet.Enums.Filters;

namespace AspNetCoreStudyingProject
{
    public class VK
    {
        private VkApi api = new VkApi();
        private ApiAuthParams prms = new ApiAuthParams() { ApplicationId = 0, Settings = Settings.All };

        public VkApi Api => api;

        public void Auth(string login, string pass)
        {
            prms.Login = login;
            prms.Password = pass;
            api.Authorize(prms);
        }

        public void ApplyTwoFactor(string code)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
                prms.TwoFactorAuthorization = () => code;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prms.Login) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prms.Password))
                api.Authorize(prms);
        }
    }
}
```

**Работает, если код в** *case "vk"* **будет такой:**

```
case "vk":
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: А почему вы используете подобную структуру приложения? Ведь удобней и правильней будет использовать контролы (MVC).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Дело в том, что изучаю Asp.Net Core по туториалу, на данный момент не особо представляю как по другому можно сделать. Ведь ранее работал только с WinForms, WPF, Console

Comment: @Arthur хочу добиться того, чтобы при вводе _localhost:(port)/social\_suicide?portal=vk&l=+380961234567&p=MyPassword_ управление переходило в мой класс VK, в котором я уже буду выполнять авторизацию и нужные мне действия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит изменить структуру проекта. Напишите middlware, или используйте атрибуты маршрутизации (второй вариант более простой и удобный). Допустим, вы хотите сделать так, чтобы при запросе на  `localhost:(port)/social_suicide` вызывался метод авторизации. Для этого создадим какой-нибудь класс

```
public class Account : Controller
{
    [Route("social_suicide")]
    public ActionResult SocialSuicide(LoginViewModel vm) // здесь используется вью-модель, которая сама создатся из строки запроса при помощи биндера моделей
    {
        // TODO: Делаем что-то
    }
}
```

Сама вью-модель авторизации может быть примерно такой:

```
public class LoginViewModel 
{
    public string Portal {get; set;}
    public string Login {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

С такой вью-моделью строка запроса будет примерно такой:

```
http://localhost:port/social_suicide?Portal=vk&Login=login&Password=password
```

Подобный подход позволит избежать кучи лишних параметров и ненужной конфигурации в классе startup. Хорошее руководство по асп нет есть [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/) . Ну и лично моё имхо: учите асп нет кор, руководство есть там же